# C++/C live Flash stream handling

Tags: c++, c, flash-media-server

I have learned C and have done some socket programming in C too. I have also done basic C++, but not templates.
I am eager to learn more about handling live video streams (not on-demand or recorded streams). Is there a good book or a website someone can suggest?

I am not looking to build a media player. I want to open a Flash media stream using C++/C then work with that data; for example, break it into 4KB pieces and resend it to another client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DirectShow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow).
[Referenece](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And as you asked - [a book](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6381&locale=en-us).

Once you're good with this you can just stream to any player. (also players that are viewed by the web)